# How do I execute this line of code for every page I visit vs just when I click on the bookmark?

Tags: javascript, url, bookmarks

I'm looking to run this line of code for every page I visit.

Currently, this is setup as a bookmark and I have to manually click on the bookmark each time I want the code to work.  Majority of the time I will need to run this on my code anyway.  Is there a way to have this code run without the bookmark button being pressed in Chrome?

`javascript:(function(){var e={a:1,style:1,script:1,iframe:1},n=function(o,r,a){for(var i,l,c=o.childNodes.length-1;c>=0;c--)i=o.childNodes[c],1==i.nodeType?(l=i.nodeName.toLowerCase(),l in e||n(i,r,a)):3==i.nodeType&&t(i,r,a)},t=function(e,n,t){for(var o,r=[];o=n.exec(e.data);)r.push(o);for(var a=r.length-1;a>=0;a--)o=r[a],e.splitText(o.index),e.nextSibling.splitText(o[1].length),e.parentNode.replaceChild(t(o[1]),e.nextSibling)};n(document.body,new RegExp("\\b([CM]{1}[0-9]+)\\b","g"),function(e){var n=document.createElement("a");return n.href="http://tools.companywebsite.com/int/search?q="+e,n.target="_blank",n.innerHTML=e,n})})()`

Comment: Perhaps run it as a TamperMonkey/GreaseMonkey script, or create a web-extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a chrome extension if you want to run same piece of JS code on every website you visit.

This might help https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you mean *bookmark*; bookmarks are just quickly accessible URLs. If this is running on whatever page you're on, it must be an *extension*.

You can make your own extension to do this or use an existing one. For your case I would recommend simply installing this extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija/related?hl=en

And saving your snippet there.